# "No such file to load" – can't install Ruby gems after Lion migration

Tags: ruby, rubygems, osx-lion

I just migrated to a new Mac with OS X Lion. For some reson I can't install new Ruby gems anymore. Or rather: I can install them, but not find them.

This is my `gem env`:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [universal-darwin11.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-11
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8
     - /Users/Jens/.gem/ruby/1.8
     - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Running the gem crack in irb works fine:

```
>> require 'rubygems'
=> false
>> require 'crack'
=> true
```

But when I try to do the same in my text editor (Textwrangler) I run into this:

```
custom_require.rb:31: in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- crack (LoadError)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Got the same issue, works in IRB though. Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a pointer in the right direction: I've had problems on Lion with different ruby versions being installed. Problem was that some programs calling ruby (in my case git for a pre-commit hook) had their $PATH variable different; as a result another version of ruby was found first (and that version didn't have the gems installed).

So to debug, try printing out the version of both rubys (rubies?), and the PATH variable (something like `print RUBY_VERSION` and `print ENV["PATH"]`; maybe also `print ENV["GEM_HOME"]`. See if that leads to anything.

FYI: for me the solution in the end was to upgrade from git 1.7.3 to 1.7.7; it wasn't clear to my why things didn't work in 1.7.3 (why the PATH was different), but who cares; it works again :))

Comment: Thanks. On those commands I get:
`print RUBY_VERSION` => `1.8.7`,
`print ENV["PATH"]` => `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/Jens/.rvm/bin`
`print ENV["GEM_HOME"]` => `nil`

Not sure how to interpret all of that.

Comment: Do you get the same result for both rubies (in irb and the "text editor" one). If those are different, that could explain the problem.

Comment: Thanks Claude. I think you found the problem. This is the output in my texteditor: `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbinnil`. My question then: how do I solve the problem?

Comment: OK, so there are some paths missing. I'm not sure this in itself is enough to cause the problem, it might be. Just to make sure, is the ruby version is different as well? Furthermore, what do you mean exactly by "in the texteditor"? Do you mean you're editing and running a program as ruby, or are you writing a plugin or something for the texteditor? In the first case, try running the program from the commandline with the "ruby" command.

Comment: No Ruby version is the same. 
And the text editor: I edit and run the program in the text editor as Ruby - that is where I get the problem. Running it from cmd/terminal works fine.

Comment: OK, I understand. Problem is that I don't know enough about Ruby to tell you what the problem is. However, further suggestions would be to print ENV["GEM_HOME"] in both rubies after requiring rubygem. I would expect it to contain something at that point. Also, perhaps looking at the `$:` variable in all cases (both rubies, before and after requiring rubygems) may give some hints ($: is the loadpaths).